# php sdk retrieve my albums and photos but cant retrieve other user albums and photos when they logged in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have implemented the facebook application that can fetch all user albums and photos when I login all my photos and albums are displayed.

But when another user log's in to the application then the application returns an empty array while when i logged in with my facebook account it shows me all albums and photos any help how to set the facebook app for it and then defining scope for it my loginurl is as:

```
$params = array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Thanks in advance 
 
Regards, 
JAVAID AHMAD

Answer (score 1):

Permissions you requested should be **reviewed and approved** by Facebook before they are applied in your App

Only App owner and test user will see those permissions before approval

You have to request review from your **App dashboard**